# Preg_Match exact Word and Output the Word from String Text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to output the match word case insensitive?
PHP Code:

```
if(preg_match("/(?i)(?<= |^)" . $Word . "(?= |$)/", $String)) {
 // If Exact Word is Match Case Insensitive
}
```

Example my string is:
Hello there, the Video was funny.

I want to get " Video " from String but because my PHP preg_match is case insensitive and i'm looking for " video " i need to get the output " Video " from the string to.

Another String Example:
Hello there, the vIDeo was funny
To get the output " vIDeo " from the string.

Another String Example:
Hello there, the vIDeowas funny.
This String don't need to output " vIDEOwas " because is not match exact word.

I need this script so i can see the way exact words is found on string after search them.

Comment: `strtolower($String)`?

Comment: i need to get the exact match from the string example " vIDeo " strtolower is making all words small ... is not helping me

Comment: Use the third parameter to specify a variable you want to catch the actual matches in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the third argument to `preg_match()` to fetch the matches; in your case there will be at most one matched pattern:

```php
$body = 'Hello there, the Video was funny';
$search = 'video';

if (preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\b/i', $body, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches[0]); // Video
}
```

A few other changes to your code:

1. Always use `preg_quote()` if you don't know where the search term comes from.
2. I use the `/i` modifier instead of `(?i)`
3. Instead of look-behind and look-ahead assertion, I use the zero width `\b` assertion instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace found match with `$Word` and then compare two strings

```
$String = 'Hello there, the Video was funny';
$Word = 'Video';
$s2 = preg_replace("/(?i)(?<= |^)" . $Word . "(?= |$)/", $Word, $String);

if ( $s2 === $String ) {
    echo "found";
}else {
    echo "NOT found";
}
```

Another solution

```
$String = 'Hello there, the Video was funny';
$Word = 'Video';
$s = explode(' ',$String);
foreach($s as $w) {
    if( $w === $Word) {
        echo $w;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The script i post is already give me if the word is found or not, i need to get the word from string so this way i can see how the word is writhed in string ... your command is doing the same what the command i post is doing ...

Comment: Added answer. Pls look